# When do we not know the distribution of residuals?

Tags: simulation, residuals

In a previous question ([How does simulation help validate model assumptions?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/641389/how-does-simulation-help-validate-model-assumptions)), I received the following comment:

"*When a model is too complex such that a derivation of the distribution of the residuals, given the assumptions, is intractable, then simulations might be used to estimate what a distribution of the residuals could look like*"

I am trying to understand in what kinds of situations could this arise.

Can someone please help me understand what kinds of situations this could be referring to and how simulation could be used to check if the model fits well in these situations?

Comment: One example is many glm models, there is an R package DHARMa, there are many posts with examples on site https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=dharma+answers%3A1